# How can I make a box have a particular aspect ratio using only html and css?

Tags: css

Can anyone think of a way to get a box to have a particular aspect ratio using only html and css? My guess is to put an image with the aspect ratio you want in the box, then absolute positioning the rest of the content on top of the image. Perhaps something magical with negative margins?

Good answers will be cross browser (gracefully degrading for IE7, older versions). Bonus points if you can overflow the box gracefully (which my basic idea doesn't account for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one quick solution here:

http://lab.veille.jp/aspectratio/

Though I'm sure with some better javascript you could do it without using an image placeholder.

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Nope, that's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. I wonder if any of the pieces there can be removed without affecting cross-browser performance...

Comment: there a reason you don't want to use jQuery/Javascript? I believe the "resizeable" has a property value for aspect ratio built in, which would be very helpful, and save you from "reinventing the wheel"

Comment: Yes, JavaScript would be easy, but I tend to do things without it whenever possible, for both philosophical and pragmatic reasons. Mostly I don't want my layout to break for people with JavaScript disabled, or if there's a JavaScript error.

Comment: Aye. I used to feel that way about JavaScript, and still might in some circumstances, but it is the gold standard now more than ever for client-side web love... thinking just about numbers, i don't think its much of a worry anymore that people have their browsers turned off... you can't please everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question recently, in a different forum, which resulted in this post: http://philarcher.org/diary/2012/scalablesquares/. The suggested solution is to use SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) for the layout part where aspect ratio should be maintained. There is an example with source code and explanations in this post.